# Is it possible to deploy the ERC721 token on private network for free?

Tags: contract-deployment, poa

I created a private network with 3 instances (one controller, 2 nodes) based on PoA on AWS.
And I checked if my custom ERC721token is deployable by using Ropspan test network.
so I have a working-private network and a deployable smart contract.

But How can I deploy that contract on my private network?
Also, I have this question.
Is it possible to deploy ERC721 smart contract for free?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process goes the same way in your private network as in the mainnet or Ropsten. You just have to define the endpoint properly to point to one of the nodes.

As it is a private network controlled by you, to deploy the contract for free you can just use a gas price of 0 for the transaction.