# Q&A: Is a token emission free?

Tags: erc-721, ethereum-classic, mint

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I have to answer question would be ethereum cost of project deployment and usage fit the product economy. Understanding the cost of minting a single token is one of important aspects here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minting a token might cost a relatively huge amount of money (~40 USD at Jan 2021) with tendency to grow which might put a cross on some types of project. More info is here https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/loq4qs/how_much_does_it_cost_to_mint_erc721_tokens/

As a workaround you might launch your own private ethereum network [with zero cost of deployment and minting](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/is-it-possible-to-deploy-the-erc721-token-on-private-network-for-free).

Comment: I ended up with private chain hosted on personal VM. Here is a deployment automation script https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/start_nodes.sh and here is more detailed deployment steps https://github.com/Gelassen/swap